# How to get the details of the 500 error with Overbyte ICS

Tags: sockets, delphi

I'm working with the TSslHttpCli component of ICS OverByte, at times I get the error 500 "Internal Server Error" I get the error code in the "OnRequestDone" event as shown below:

```
procedure TFFormCot.SslHttpCotRequestDone(Sender: TObject;
  RqType: THttpRequest; ErrCode: Word);
var
 SslHttpCli : TSslHttpCli;
begin
 try
  SslHttpCli := Sender as TSslHttpCli;

  if ErrCode <> 0 then
    begin
     Memo1.lines.add('ICS:Erro:CT-01: Falha na solicitação ao servidor  - ErrCode:[' + IntToStr(ErrCode) +  '][' + SslHttpCli.ReasonPhrase + ']');
    end;

  if SslHttpCli.StatusCode <> 200 then
    begin
         Memo1.lines.add('ICS:Erro:CT-01.A: ' + IntToStr(SslHttpCli.StatusCode) + ' ' + SslHttpCli.ReasonPhrase);
    end;
end;
```

But I can not get the details of error 500.

the html is not available, you may have some message stating the reason for the error, such as a wrong sent parameter. How do I get the html in this case, or the header received?

Comment: In general, 500 is a serious error, and quite often there isn't much other information. IIS for example can be configured to show the information only for internal visits, but hide it for others, because it can contain sensitive information. The information itself is usually just a stack trace. When the server knows what's wrong (like invalid input parameter, like you say), it should return an error from the 400 range, with optionally more detailed information. 500 basically means: I'm dead, and I don't know why. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_Server_errors

Comment: You may try https://httpstat.us/500 (a free service) to verify that the problem is the server, not your code or ICS. The https://httpstat.us/500 URL returns a HTTP 500 status code and a HTML body which is the plain text string "500 Internal Server Error"